# React.js: Delete operation and refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented a delete operation. When this is done I make a redirect on the main page but I would like it to be automatically updated instead I have to update it again (calling a getEntities to get the values ​​back)

reducer.ts

```
export const getEntities = createAsyncThunk('services/getEntities', async (param: parameters) => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}${param.sortParam ? `?page=${param.pageParam}&size=${20}&sort=${param.sortParam}` : ''}`;
  const response = await axios.get<any>(requestUrl);
  return response;
});

export const deleteEntity = createAsyncThunk('services/deleteEntity', async (id: any) => {
  const response = await axios.delete<any>(`${apiUrl}/${id}`);
  return response;
})
```

deletePage.tsx

```
const handleClose = () => {
        props.history.push('/service');
    };


    const confirmDelete = () => {
        dispatch(deleteEntity(property.entity.id))
            .then((resp: any) => {
                if (resp.payload.status === 204) {
                    handleClose();
                }
            })
    };
```

So in my "service" page I have to call getEntities again to get the updated list (without the deleted element).

In your opinion How can I do to avoid having to manually call getEntities after deletion?

Comment: Why do you have to call getEntities rather than removing the entity locally? Redux thunks allow you to dispatch updates to the store

Comment: Because The deleted element remains visible until I call the getEntities

Answer (score 1):

By your `props` I'm guessing you're using `react-router`. To refresh a route you would use `history.go(0)`.

Comment: I tried what you suggest and it is a good solution :) I had thought of calling the getEntities to update only the content